# How not to get parent div pushed back when text is long and has white

Tags: html, css, text, next.js, tailwind-css

[image]Basically I am trying to achieve responsive interface for my webapp but I'm having a problem on my div container width / text font sizing

```
  return (
    <div className="whitespace-nowrap ml-auto mr-auto pl-2 pr-2 bg-red-600 min-w-full">
      <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text
      </span>
    </div>
  );
```

On small devices, I still want the text to fit the available width (with a scaled down font size), but as you can see on the screenshot, the body container gets pushed back because of this non wrapping text (the black part) leaving the  grey color to appear behind

```
return (
    <Html lang="en" data-theme="business">
      <Head></Head>

      <body className="bg-black min-w-full m-0">
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
```

Layout.tsx:

```
[![export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutParams) {][1]][1]
  return <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col">{children}</div>;
}
```

I expect the body the have the same size as the red div, please help

Comment: Your issue is that the content of 'text text...' in mobile devices wont show completely without scrolling, from user experience perspective you need to show ALL the content inside the mobile screen. Try adding `width:100%` in 'text text...' parent div or create an snippet somewhere in online code editor so it's easier to figure out for us